# What is needed for framework with dependency to pod?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, frameworks, cocoapods

Target: a framework within which the pod is used.

Now I see it like this:

1. Created framework with "Cocoa Touch Framework" template.
2. Add some code. **In places where I need to use a third-party** code (Alamofire, for example), I imported Alamofire, if I try to build an application, I get an error that says that I do not have Alamofire.
3. Installed pod. Created podspec. In dependency - added Alamofire.
4. Register pod.
5. Installed pod with my framework to other project (it is also installed Alamofire) and use my code.

Do I understand correctly what needs to be done? That's why I'm now stopping at point 4 because of errors. Usually they sound like "you're trying to import Alamofire, but you do not have it".

[image]

**Upd:**
Podspec:

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|

  s.name         = "Test"
  s.version      = "0.0.1"
  s.summary      = "A short description."
  s.description  = "A not short, but not long description of Test."
  s.homepage     = "https://github.com/..."
  s.license      = "MIT"
  s.author       = { "name" => "email" }
  s.platform     = :ios, "10.0"

  s.source       = { :git => "https://github.com/...", :tag => "0.0.1" }
  s.source_files = "Test/**/*"
  #s.public_header_files = "Test/**/*.h"

  #s.dependency "Moya", "~> 10.0"
  #s.dependency "ObjectMapper", "= 3.1.0"
  #s.dependency "SAMKeychain", "~> 1.5.2"

end
```

Comment: try add  `s.swift_version = '4.0'` on `.podspec`

Comment: @a.masri It help with warning about swift version. But not with errors.

Comment: ok please add `.podspec` file

Comment: @a.masri added to question.

Comment: try this command `pod spec lint --use-libraries`

Comment: read this documentation https://guides.cocoapods.org/terminal/commands.html#pod_trunk_push

Comment: @a.masri unfortunately no one option helped me.

Comment: @Yume Are you using the latest CocoaPods version?